# serialize and unserialize $_session['cart']

Tags: php, mysql

I have a shooping cart and I would like to save the $_SESSION['cart'] which contains the $product_id => $quantity of the products that the user have choosen.
For example:

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [366] => 2000
        [215] => 456
    )
```

First I serialize the $_SESSION['cart'] before I INSERT IT in my data base.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['cart']) 
{
    $pedido= serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
}
?>

$sql1="insert into pedido(orden) values ('$pedido')";
```

Now in a different page I want to view the $_SESSION['cart']. So I use:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT orden FROM pedido where id_pedido = '$ID'";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conexio) or die("Error al consultar: ".mysql_error()); 
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($rs2);
$id_usuario=$row2[0];
$_SESSION['cartguardado']= unserialize($id_usuario);
```

I know that In this last step I am doing something wrong.  Any body could help me and help me finding the mistake?

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Did you intend to have $_SESSION['cartguardado'] named that way or should it still be named $_SESSION['cart']?

Comment: Are you seeing an error? If not, what are you seeing that you're not expecting? Do you know that the [use of the mysql extension is discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)?

Comment: Can you isolate where the error is? We don't know how all your variables are setup/named and we can't help you if we don't know if it's the error with the code or an error with a previously set variable...

Comment: Are you actually gettign any rows returned in your result set?  How do you know what to use for `$ID`?

Comment: I dont receive any error when I do $_SESSION['cartguardado']= unserialize($id_usuario); The $_SESSION is empty.

Comment: Have you called `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes I have called session_start() at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to output $row2

```
$sql2 = "SELECT orden FROM pedido where id_pedido = '$ID'";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conexio) or die("Error al consultar: ".mysql_error()); 
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($rs2);
print_r($row2);
$id_usuario=$row2[0];
$_SESSION['cartguardado']= unserialize($id_usuario);
```

if $row2[0] is empty so something wrong with your data

Comment: When I do print_r($row2) I get: Array ( [0] => Array [orden] => Array )

Comment: what says print("SELECT orden FROM pedido where id_pedido = '$ID'");

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you serialized the session code, but didn't present it in a way you can use for Php program i.e

```
if($_SESSION['cart']) 
{
    $pedido= serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

From my little experience I think you need to first unserialize the code so you can use it i.e

```
if($_SESSION['cart']) 
{
    $pedido = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
}
```